# Separating Chars and Ints in a String

Tags: string, haskell

Is there any way of doing something like this?

> takeWhile (Char) "I have no idea how to do this 2013"

I know what I did isn't possible, but is there a way to obtain "I have no idea how to do this" without using things like tail or last or something of the sort? And then save the string in a variable and the number in another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
ghci> break isNumber "I have no idea how to do this 2013"
("I have no idea how to do this ","2013")
```

Make sure that you import `isNumber` from `Data.Char`

If you want to store it in some variable, just use `fst` and `snd` functions for accessing the data from the pair.

Example in ghci:

```
ghci> let pair = break isNumber "I have no idea how to do this 2013"
ghci> let stringData = fst pair
ghci> let numData = snd pair
```

Note that the numData contains the integers in String format.

Comment: I though about somwthing similar, a splitOn, but how can I save both Strings in a variable when doing that?

Comment: @ipg24 Updated in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

There's `isAlpha` from `Data.Char`. You'll want to augment it with `isSpace`.

```
>>> takeWhile (\c -> isAlpha c || isSpace c) "I have no idea how to do this 2013"
"I have no idea how to do this "
```

You could also do `not . isNumber`

```
>>> takeWhile (not . isNumber) "I have no idea how to do this 2013"
"I have no idea how to do this "
```